# What can be the replacement tag for colspan and rowspan attribute of <td>

Tags: java, html, html-table, itext

I am using IText for PDF generation, but sometimes while generating PDF for html code having rowspan and colspan as table data (`<td>`) fails to generate PDF. I am looking for alternative so that I can replace that with colspan/rowspan.

For example,
List (`<li>`) tag is supported.

so I replace that tag with below,

```
<table cellpadding="2" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="4%" align="center">&#8226;</td>
<td valign="top"> Data </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Which html-to-pdf class of iText do you use? There were/are the `HTMLWorker`, the `XMLWorker`, and the `HtmlConverter`. Read [this](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/intro) for the differences.

Comment: I am using XMLWorker. And Itext version is 5.1. In Itext 5 HTMLWorker has very less support for CSS, and HTMLCoverter is available in Itext 7.

Comment: Have you at least tried updating itext to the current 5.x version? That should be a 5.5.xx version.

Comment: Itext 5.5 also does not support these tags.

Comment: Ok. Thought it might be worth trying, much changed between 5.1 and 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

`colspan` and `rowspan` extend a `td` cell either horizontally or vertically for the size defined by its respective value. So the only real solution would be to avoid using those values and replace them with the missing `td` elements, which can be tricky for some cases in order to get the same visual result.

For instance an easy to replace case is this:

```html
<tr>
  <td>Cell 1</td>
  <td>Cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">Cell 1</td>
</tr>
```

Which can be rewritten as:

```html
<tr>
  <td>Cell 1</td>
  <td>Cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Cell 1</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

But the visual result will be far from the same as with `colspan` attribute.

Comment: Yes the visuals change drastically. Specially when there is a lot of data in replaced <td> tag.